# Java Mail: force "Content-Transfer-Encoding" to be "quoted-printable"

Tags: java, email, character-encoding, gmail, jakarta-mail

Currently, the email shows the following headers for the MimeBodyPart in question:

```
------=_Part_56_339247379.1438186660985
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Here's what the headers section SHOULD show:

```
----boundary_0_e825c994-ed10-443c-a2e7-d107b27d31dd
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Here's how I'm attempting to force quoted-printable:

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
```

How do I force Content-Transfer-Encoding to be quoted-printable? I'm connecting to my gmail's mail servers, idk if that makes any difference. Maybe that header gets overriden by google.

Comment: Why do you think the Content-Transfer-Encoding **should** be quoted-printable?  Normally JavaMail will choose an appropriate encoding based on the content of your message.

Setting the header should work to override JavaMail's choice.  If you use Message.writeTo to write out the message before you send it, does it have the right header?

Comment: "Why do you think the Content-Transfer-Encoding should be quoted-printable?"
I don't. However, the emails we're sending programmatically have to be processed by a third party's project.

Setting the header doesn't seem to have any effects. Printing the headers yields no changes.

I'm setting the text like so:
messageBodyPart.setText("");

Comment: So you're dealing with a buggy third party program that doesn't understand how to properly handle MIME messages?  Sigh.  What version of JavaMail are you using?  Do you have a simple program that reproduces the bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had a variation on this problem with the main body of an email. I was tasked with replicating the output of another program that always used quoted printable even when not required. What finally worked was to ensure that I set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header **after** I added the text to the message. Perhaps the same thing will work with a mime-part. Try setting the header after setting the content (presumably overriding whatever JavaMail decided when you set the content).

FWIW, I was working with JavaMail 1.5.5